# Using a for loop with predict function in R

Tags: r, lasso-regression

I've built a series of lasso regression models from training data, each with a different bound. My code is as follows:

```
Y <- c(3300, 2600, 2500, 2475, 2313, 2175, 600, 460)
V2 <- c(0.272, 0.269, 0.249, 0.260, 0.273, 0.291, 0.258, 0.228)
V3 <- c(0.302, 0.335, 0.337, 0.292, 0.346, 0.379, 0.370, 0.279)
V4 <- c(69, 58, 54, 59, 87, 104, 34, 16)
V5 <- c(153, 111, 115, 128, 169, 170, 86, 38)
V6 <- c(21, 17, 15, 22, 28, 32, 14, 7)

data <- data.frame(Y, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)

test.sample <- sample(1:8, 3)
train <- data[-test.sample,]
test <- data[test.sample,]

library(lasso2)
seq1 <- seq(1, 5, by = 1)
seq2 <- seq(6, 10, by = 2)
seq3 <- c(seq1, seq2)
lasso <- l1ce(Y ~ ., data = train, standardize = FALSE, 
              absolute.t = TRUE, bound = seq3)
```

I would like to make predictions from each model on testing data. I assume this is most easily done using a for loop with the predict function, however I'm new to R and unfamiliar with for loops. I'm wondering if someone can give me a hand.

Comment: Please make the question more reproducible by providing a sample of `data.train`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Nelson! I've made the addition.